# Segmentation Fault(core dumped): Simple program but not working

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

pac()
{
    int i,j,k,size;

    char ns[size];
    int nss[size];
    printf("ENTER THE NUMBER OF STUDENTS: ");
    scanf("%d",size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("ENTER THE NAME OF STUDENT: ");
        scanf("%c",ns[i]);
    }
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        printf("ENTER THE MARKS OF THE STUDENT: ");
        scanf("%d",nss[j]);
    }


    for(k=0;k<size;k++)
    {
        printf("%c",ns[i]);
    }
}

main()

{

pac();

}
```

I know the error is too small but I am new to C so kindly let me know the bug.
There is a segmentation fault in this code after taking the first input of number of students.

Comment: `size` is not initialized and then you use it to set an array size, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Changing the value of `size` will not magically resize your arrays. You probably need dynamic allocation (`malloc`) for this.

Comment: Shafik, that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @paxdiablo you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%d",size);  
           ^You missed & operator here.
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &size);
```

Now since you are using VLAs, you need to place your declaration of your VLAs after getting the value of `size`.

```
printf("ENTER THE NUMBER OF STUDENTS: ");
scanf("%d", &size);
char ns[size];
int nss[size];
```

Comment: Closer. It still only allows a one-character name for each student.

Answer (score 0):

`size` is not initialized and then you use it to set an array size, this is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). As Fred said setting `size` later on won't re-size your arrays *magically*.

You should be calling `scanf` before you intialize the arrays but you need to pass in a pointer:

```
scanf("%d",&size);
           ^
```

You are also relying on implicit int for both `main` and `pac`, you should explicitly set their return type which should be `int` for `main` and probably `void` for `pac`.

You should be seeing warnings for most of these without even having to turn them on. Both `gcc` and `clang` provide warnings for *implicit int* returns and incorrect use of `scanf`, similar to this:

> warning: return type defaults to 'int' [enabled by default]
>
> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat]

and turning up warnings also gets me a warning for using `size` initialized:

> warning: 'size' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Answer (score 0):

smells like a homework programming assignment...

```
#include <stdio.h>
pac()
{
    int i,j,k,size;

    printf("ENTER THE NUMBER OF STUDENTS: ");
    scanf("%d",&size); // <-- need to pass in the address of size

    do { // <-- you need this to establish the size for array creation
        char ns[size];
        int nss[size];

        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            printf("ENTER THE NAME OF STUDENT: ");
            scanf("%c",&(ns[i])); // <-- need the address here, too
        }
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            printf("ENTER THE MARKS OF THE STUDENT: ");
            scanf("%d",&(nss[j])); // <-- and again here
        }


        for(k=0;k<size;k++)
        {
            printf("%c",ns[i]);
        }
    } while(0);
}

main()

{

    pac();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of all answers.

1. size is not initialized (already said)
2. scanf's second argument must be a pointer (&size, &ns[i], ...)
3. Allocate space dynamically based on value of size or have ns and nss with fix enough size (#define MAX_SIZE 1000 and check size < MAX_SIZE).

You can code it like this:

```
void pac()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int size;

    char *ns;
    int  *nss;

    printf("ENTER THE NUMBER OF STUDENTS: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    /* Check size */

    if (size > 0)
    {
        ns  = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        nss = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

        /* check ns and nss are not NULL and then continue */

        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("ENTER THE NAME OF STUDENT: ");
            scanf("%c",&ns[i]);
        }

        for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("ENTER THE MARKS OF THE STUDENT: ");
            scanf("%d", &nss[j]);
        }


        for(k = 0;k < size; k++)
        {
            printf("%c", ns[i]);
        }
    }
}
```